# Entity Framework - Get Records : Comma separated string (or List<string>) is contained within a collection of entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Given entities

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query the Products table to retrieve products with any of the categories given as a comma separated list.

So, for example I want to get products with categories "Electronics" AND/OR "Kitchen Equipment"

If it wasn't a collection, I would do like this: E.g.

```
Products.Where(p => "Oven,Kettle".Contains(p.ProductName));
```

But this obviously does not work:

```
Products.Where(p => "Electronics,Kitchen Equipment".Contains(p.Categories.CategoryName));
```

also tried:

```
Products.Where(p => "Electronics,Kitchen Equipment".Any(x => p.Categories.Any(pcat => pcat.CategoryName == x.ToString()))).Take(100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var categories = new[] { "Electronics", "Kitchen Equipment" };

var productsQuery = Products
    .Where(p => p.Categories.Any(pcat => categories.Contains(pcat.CategoryName)))
    .Take(100);
```

Comment: Note: this it can give incorrect results, if the list is { "Electronics", "Kitchen Equipment", "Kitchen" } because Contains will match both  "Kitchen Equipment" and "Kitchen".. (In a search that tried to get only "Kitchen")

Comment: @AlfNielsen No, `categories` is an array, so `Enumerable.Contains` will check for equality. If `categories` was defined as a string i.e. `var categories = "Electronics, Kitchen Equipment";` they your point would be valid.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct here. I was looking for a solution when the DB contains a comma separated list (Not an actual list), which will have the problem I describe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass IEnumerable into Where clause:

```cs
var names = "Oven,Kettle".Split(',');
var query = Products.Where(p => names.Contains(p.ProductName));
```

Comment: If I was looking for a single text field I would do this. I am looking to match any of the comma separated strings with any of the collection items. Thank you for spending time to answer my question though!